# Determining the size of a PNG from raw bytes

Tags: python-imaging-library

I'm trying to load a sequence of PNG images concatenated together as bytes; I know the number of images, but not their individual file sizes.

Loading the first image is easy with something like

```py
import io
from PIL import Image
buffer = io.BytesIO(image_bytearray)
image = Image.open(buffer)
image.load()
```

However, I'm not sure how to handle the subsequent images. Two approaches that seem to work but might be too brittle:

1. Split the bytes based on the PNG header e.g. `image_bytearray.split(b"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n")`. This seems to work, but I'm worried in some edge cases this could appear in a non-header location.
2. Use `BytesIO.tell()` to determine how much of the stream was read. This appears to be 4 bytes less than the actual file size; I can add 4 to account for this, but I'm not this won't change in a later version.

Here's a simple example that illustrates the two approaches:

```py
import io
import sys
from PIL import Image
import PIL

def setup_bytes():
    """
    Concatenate the bytes of some images. The actual images don't matter
    """
    files = ["Tests/images/hopper.png", "Tests/images/test-card.png"]
    bytes_out = bytes()
    for file in files:
        im = Image.open(file)
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        im.save(buffer, format="PNG")
        print(f"writing {len(buffer.getvalue())} bytes")
        bytes_out += buffer.getvalue()

    return bytes_out

def read_split(bytes_in):
    png_header = b"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n"
    images_out = []
    image_byte_splits = bytes_in.split(png_header)

    for image_bytes in image_byte_splits:
        if len(image_bytes) == 0:
            continue
        # add back the header
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(png_header + image_bytes))
        image.load()
        print(f"read {len(png_header) + len(image_bytes)} bytes")
        images_out.append(image)
    return images_out

def read_streaming(bytes_in):
    images_out = []
    bytes_read = 0
    # Read the images back from the bytes (without knowing the sizes).
    while bytes_read < len(bytes_in):
        buffer = io.BytesIO(bytes_in[bytes_read:])
        image = Image.open(buffer)
        image.load()
        images_out.append(image)

        # Start the next read at the end of the current image.
        # These extra 4 bytes appear necessary.
        read = buffer.tell() + 4
        print(f"read {read} bytes?")
        bytes_read += read
    return images_out


def main():
    print(f"python sys.version = {sys.version}")
    print(f"Pillow version = {PIL.__version__}")
    b = setup_bytes()
    read_split(b)
    read_streaming(b)

main()
```

My questions are:

1. Is splitting safe? Is there a chance that the header could also appear in the body of an image?
2. Is adding an offset to `tell()` safe? Is there a way to get the image loading to leave the position at the actual end of the file?
3. Is there a better way to do this in general? Some of the classes in `PngImagePlugin.py` look like they'd be useful to examine the chunks without actually decompressing.